# Why is node failing to find SubmitEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to add unit tests using jest to my React application.

I have the following code in my test, but when I run it, I am getting "ReferenceError: SubmitEvent is not defined".

```
taskInputForm.dispatchEvent(new SubmitEvent("submit"), { bubbles: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

SubmitEvent is relatively recent, maybe the browser you used is not up to date.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/SubmitEvent